# Keyboard ubuntu 22.04 was not working

Tags: 22.04

I found a weird problem with my laptop, I have on it ubuntu 22.04
It's both control buttons suddenly stopped working

.. I thought something is wrong with the keyboard. I tried restarting everything. but keyboard was not working

I got desperate .. and opened this link for testing the control key
https://en.key-test.ru/
and started hitting they control button, again and again, and both controls at the same time.. suddenly the control started working..
=> it still has the problem, and when I hit control buttons multiple times, it works again.

what is the issue?

Comment: This sounds like a hardware problem. Possibly dirty keyboard?
Have you tried an external (USB) keyboard?